# Countdown to restart at 3 AM, 9 AM, 3 PM and 9 PM

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown

I'm looking for a countdown script that can say "Restart in: x hours, x minutes and x seconds." for a overview of my servers on my website. (It's for a gaming server that restarts every 6 hours)

I found a countdown script that does this, but I can't figure out how to run it, this is the script and how I tried to put it on the website.

```
var serverRestartHours = [3,9,15,21]; // in UTC
var startTime = new Date(); 

var hoursOffset = startTime.getTimezoneOffset()/60;
var currentHourUTC = startTime.getHours()+hoursOffset;
var nextRestartHour = 0;

for (i = 0; i < serverRestartHours.length; i++) {
if(serverRestartHours[i] > currentHourUTC){
    nextRestartHour = serverRestartHours[i];
    break;
}
}
if(currentHourUTC >= serverRestartHours[serverRestartHours.length-1])
nextRestartHour = serverRestartHours[0];

var endTime = new Date();
endTime.setMinutes(0);
endTime.setSeconds(0);
endTime.setHours(nextRestartHour-(endTime.getTimezoneOffset()/60));
console.log(endTime);

function update(){
var currentTime = new Date();

var remainingTime = new Date();
remainingTime.setTime(endTime.getTime()-currentTime.getTime());
if(remainingTime<0)
    return;

if(remainingTime.getHours()<=1)
    $("#note").text(remainingTime.getMinutes()+" minutes and "+remainingTime.getSeconds() + " seconds");
else
    $("#note").text(remainingTime.getHours()-1+" hours, "+remainingTime.getMinutes()+" minutes and "+remainingTime.getSeconds() + " seconds");

}
update();
setInterval(update,1000);
```

I tried including this on my website (Running SMF with SimplePortal, tried to implement this in a HTML block)

```
<div style="margin:12px;">Restart in: <span id="note"></span>
<script type="text/javascript" src="countdown.js"></script>
</div>
```

All I get by doing this is normal font saying "Restart in: " instead of "Restart in: x hours, x minutes and x seconds"

Help anyone?

Comment: It seems to use jQuery. Did you include the jQuery library on your page? Since it uses so little, you could just change `$("#note").text("string");` to be `document.getElementById("note").innerHTML = "string";` and not have to rely on jQuery

Comment: Like I said, I have no idea of how to get this to work, I have about none experience or knowledge in js, so I can't answer that question, but most likely not.

Comment: @Ian, that did not seem to have done the trick. I changed it to this: `document.getElementById("note").innerHTML = remainingTime.getMinutes()+" minutes and "+remainingTime.getSeconds() + " seconds";` and `document.getElementById("note").innerHTML = remainingTime.getHours()-1+" hours, "+remainingTime.getMinutes()+" minutes and "+remainingTime.getSeconds() + " seconds";
`

Comment: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/7WbE6/) Take a look there and see if you see anything weird or something that would prevent it from working.

Answer (score 1):

Note that setInterval runs at *about* the requested interval, it will gradually drift later. If you want something to update as close as reasonable to a certain time, better to use setTimeout and estimate how long it needs to wait.

Also, the code seems more verbose than it needs to be. If the updates are at 6 hourly intervals from 0300, you can do:

```
<script>
// Countdown in hh:mm:ss to next 0300, 0900, 1500 or 2100
// Uses local time
function timeToUpdate() {

  // Add leading zero to numbers less than 10
  function z(n) {return (n < 10? '0' : '') + n;}

  var now = new Date();

  // Calculate seconds to go, convert 60 to 00
  var secsToGo = (60 - now.getSeconds()) % 60;

  // Calculate minutes to go. If secs at 0, add 1
  var minsToGo = (59 - now.getMinutes() + !secsToGo) % 60;

  // Calculate hours to go. If secs and mins at 0, add 1
  var hoursToGo = 5 - ((now.getHours() + 3) % 6) + !(minsToGo + secsToGo); 

  // Return formatted string
  return z(hoursToGo) + ':' + z(minsToGo) + ':' + z(secsToGo);
}

function updateClock() {

  // Update counter
  document.getElementById('timeToGo').innerHTML = timeToUpdate();

  // Run just after next full second
  var lag = 1020 - (new Date()).getMilliseconds();
  setTimeout(updateClock, lag);
}
</script>

<button onclick="updateClock()">Start countdown</button>
<div>Restart in: <span id="timeToGo"></span></div>
```

The above uses local time, to use UTC, change to UTC methods (e.g. `now.getUTCHours()`).